# How to add chinese characters to FCITX / Keyboard input

Tags: keyboard, chinese, fcitx, korean

I am using FCITX input for Korean (hangul to hanja) and there are surprisingly a LOT of chinese characters that don't show when typing it. I'd like to contribute more characters and more accurate predictions to this system. How can I do this?

For example:

The 頉 character is missing when I type. This sino-korean word is pretty common yet it doesn't display when I type it.

TL:DR - I'd like to add and edit the chinese characters that will pop up when I input.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu, since President Park (father) abolished Chinese and Japanese from Korean, almost no one writes them there. You can add either Chinese in the language support to type these characters.

Answer (score 0):

**Type 頉 character by Unicode Input**

<kbd>Contorol</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>U</kbd> 9809 <kbd>Space</kbd>

You need to find unicode for the character beforehand, and this is useful doesn't matter the input method you use, always works. Even it looks like Tofu.

---

**How to use dictionary in the fcitx mozc**

[image: Mozc Icon]

Click on the Mozc icon あ from the menu bar.

[image: Mozc menu]

Open *Dictionary Tool*

[image: Registering]

Resister the character or a word like this. I am not sure Korean version fcitx does have this feature, you need a full packages of Chinese or Japanese IME.

`sudo apt install fcitx-mozc`

To make input method works under Japanese or Chinese, go to System Settings > Language Support, add and install Chinese (for Simplified character) or/and Taiwanese, Japanese or Cantonese (for traditional or Japanese Kanji characters)

Long postscript:

Installing Chinese set, you can get 頉 easier and hard to get 顎 or 頤. Installing traditional characters the way around it. Anyway, for the Chinese character readers, for a standard opinion complicated is better for associating the original character. For the most of them 车 is impossible to associate 車 until someone gives me a hint, such as 火车 and 汽车站 then I understand what 车 means. The same goes 东京 ＝ 東京, now look at these characters 车 and 东 are too simple for the 車 and 東. I found Taiwanese and Cantonese traditional Chinese characters very easy to understand, e.g. 台北車站 = 臺北車驛 = 台北駅 + Taipei station. That's something like the word 'abolere' into 'abolish', all the European people have no difficult to convert them. Main land Chinese would have a very different opinion, I don't care. It's up to you which to use.